# How do I set trial period to android application before publishing in android market?

Tags: android

I have one query regarding android market. Actually I am going to launch an android application in market. I have read all steps before launching app in market means that versioning of app, signing of app and licensing of app. Actually the licensing of app is only for paid app. But I am going to launch my app using trial period. Suppose I want to publish my app for 30 days free to the user. After 30 days when user going to open that app, it will not be further accessible to the user. It will tell to the user to purchase it from the market.

is Licensing of app will be useful in this case? I have read that docs, but i am not getting the clear idea. Please suggest me what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do that that get's around uninstalling and reinstalling the app. You can do it by autogenerating some sort of login and using a unique device ID and communicating it to a server you own.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have done some coding like when trial period get's expired, it will generate one alert box telling the user that "Please purchase it from android market". The application will not be accessible to the user for further use. But, he will uninstall the app and reinstall again. The solution that you have given here that we have to send unique device ID to the server... How can it will be done in android market? There is no any option available to store the device ID and it will check again at the time of installing the app. is this correct?? please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You would have to have your own server store that, and when you run at some point in the future, check against that.

Answer (score 0):

The licensing service is only available on paid apps. That means that there is no way to use the licensing service with your free trial app.

If you want to avoid a user reinstalling the app and using it for 30 days again Mike is right. Get the device ID or IMEI of the handset, for privacy reasons please generate a hash from the id and store the hash on your own server component. Now every time an app starts the hash is sent to the server and the server replies how many days the user used your app.

Answer (score -4):

Licensing of app is useful for that u can use that
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html